# React handle click in reusable stateless component when condition is true

Tags: reactjs

I have on component which is stateless and it is used in both parent component

```
<div onClick={() => handleClick()}><div>
```

I have to add handle click function but only for one of them. I have one bool variable which is responsible for that e.g. shouldHandleClick.

So I need to write something like but it works for cases with props, strings etc. etc.

`<div {shouldHandleClick ? onClick={() => handleClick()} : null}><div>`

Do you have any ideas otherwise i will handle click in the second component which doesn`t need this handle click function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<div onClick={this.props.shouldHandleClick ? this.handleClick : null}><div>`

And send `shouldHandleClick` with props to activate or deactivate click function.

Comment: Be careful with context `this`

Comment: What wrong can be with context in ternary operator?

Comment: `this.handleClick` will be called from event listener. If you've not bound `this` directly to you handler it could cause problems.

Comment: I don`t have this in my case because this child component which handles the click is stateless. Off course, I bound this in the parent component.  Btw everything works as expected - thanks for the syntax hints :))

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are almost there:

```
<div onClick={shouldHandleClick ? handleClick : null}></div>
```